# variables in config file are not available in class

Tags: php

I have a simple question, but I can't seem to resolve it. I have a config file, containing variables formatted as:

```
$config['something'] = 'value';
```

This file in being included in an index.php, where I also have an __autoload function. All works alright, the config file is available within the index.php (I can output each value) and the autoloader does the job when I initiate a class or call a static object.

The problem is that I try to use those config values as arguments in the classes I load and I get the "undefined variable: config" error for each of these. What am I doing wrong?

**config.php**

```
$config['item1'] = 'value1';
$config['item2'] = 'value2';
$config['item3'] = 'value3';
```

**index.php**

```
require_once('config.php');
function __autoload()...
```

**class.mysql.php**

```
function connect() {
    mysqli_connect($connect['host'] etc.                            
...
```

Obviously, the above is a simplified version of what I'm doing to illustrate the relationship between the files. How do I get the variables in config.php to be available in a class that's autoloaded?

Thank you!

Comment: without $config = array();, I get 4 notices and an error. if I add the $config = array(); line, the notices dissappear, but the error remains:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$config' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a scope issue the variable created outside of a function are not accessible inside it, and variable create inside of a function are not accessible outside it.

More informations here : [PHP Variable Scpope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

You have two solutions :

1. *Pass the $config array into the function as an argument*

**Index.php**

```
require_once('config.php');
function __autoload($config)...
```

**class.mysql.php**

```
function connect($config) {
    mysqli_connect($connect['host'] etc.
```

See it in action : http://3v4l.org/RYfc0

2. *Use global*

**Index.php**

```
require_once('config.php');
function __autoload()...
```

**class.mysql.php**

```
function connect() {
    //If you want to use the $config variable here
    global $config;
    mysqli_connect($connect['host'] etc.
```

See it in action : http://3v4l.org/ES4ej

Personally I rather prefer using the first solution as it help me to easier understand where the `$config` variable come from

Comment: this works, thanks a lot. for the future, is there a "best practice" to avoid having to do this? maybe creating a config class and making all the items available globally?

Comment: @Chris I tend to use static class it already has a global scope, you can manipulate it with ease and it's easier to maintain